# How to check substring in Ocelot claims check?

Tags: asp.net, api-gateway, ocelot

We have an Ocelot gateway in front of our microservices. We need to check claims in a jwt.

Claims come from custom claims requests from adb2c. Since adb2c doesn't support arrays for custom claims, we have them as (length is arbitrary):

```
permissions: "p1,p2,p3"
```

What we want to do on the Ocelot side is:

```
"RouteClaimsRequirement": {
    "permissions": "p2"
  }
```

in other words, we want to check that user's claim string contains the string `p2`.

Ideally, it would be able to check if multiple substrings are contained within the `permissions` string. So, like, *ensure that permissions string contains both, `p1` and `p3` substring*.

Is there a way to achieve this?